# I have problem with interrupt on 16f690

Tags: pic

I am using pic16f690 and mikroc pro. I want to create interrupt on Rb4 and Rb5 (on those pins I have encoder) and when interrapt came i want to turn on LED.
But compiler gives me a error:
74 317 Operator '.' is not applicable to these operands 'INTCON' MyProject.c
Where i made mistake?
Please help me.

```
void interrupt()   
{
   if ( INTCON.RBIF==1)
   {
        LED=1;         
        INTCON.RBIF = 0;        // Clear interrupt flag

   }//end intcon.RBIF if
}//end ISR

void main()
{
    OPTION_REG=0x80;
    ANSEL=0x00;
    ANSELH=0x00;

    CM1CON0=0x00;
    CM2CON0=0x00;

    T1CON=0x00;

    TRISA=0b00000011;
    PORTA=0x00;

    TRISB=0b00111111;
    PORTB=0xff;

    TRISC=0x00;
    PORTC=0x40;

    INTCON.RBIF = 0;     // Clear interrupt flag prior to enable
    INTCON.RBIE = 1;     // enable on change interrupts
    INTCON.GIE  = 1;     // enable Global interrupts
```

Comment: Try ```INTCONbits.GIE```.

Answer (score 1):

Your template is faulty a little bit . You have to wait anywhere until overflow a interrupt.

Please try Below template that I edited version.

```
void main()   
{   
    OPTION_REG=0x80;  
    ANSEL=0x00;
    ANSELH=0x00; 
    CM1CON0=0x00;        
    CM2CON0=0x00; 
    T1CON=0x00;
    TRISA=0b00000011; PORTA=0x00;
    TRISB=0b00111111; PORTB=0xff; 
    TRISC=0x00; PORTC=0x40;
    INTCON.RBIF = 0; // Clear interrupt flag prior to enable  
    INTCON.RBIE= 1; // enable on change interrupts  
    INTCON.GIE = 1; // enable Global interrupts 
    while(1){__delay_us(1)} 
}


void interrupt isr(void)  
{ 
   if ( INTCON.RBIF==1)  
   { 
      LED^=1; //Invert for test.
      INTCON.RBIF = 0; 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is trying to tell you something - you are using incorrect bit definitions. The 16F690 does not have bits called `RBIF` and `RBIE`, instead it has `RABIF` and `RABIE`. Always read the datasheet before writing any code!

[image]